# Elixir - Calling / Invoking Macros - UndefinedFunctionError

Tags: elixir

Why does Elixir report `UndefinedFunctionError` when calling a macro using `Module.macroName` syntax in an `.exs` file?  I seem to able to call Macro only if I have another function that calls the macro and I call the function instead of macro.

Below code demonstrates this:

```
defmodule Sample do
  defmacro doIt(expression) do
    quote do
      IO.puts unquote(expression)
    end
  end

  def doFunc(e), do: doIt(e)
end

Sample.doFunc "Hello World via Function" # Works fine
Sample.doIt "Hello World from Macro!" # Gives error
```

Output

```
Hello World via Function
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Sample.doIt/1
    Sample.doIt("Hello World from Macro!")
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:307: Code.require_file/2
```

The [Elixir documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#our-first-macro) example uses `iex`, instead of calling macro in the `.exs` file.  Even above code, if we remove calls to `Sample.doIt`  and load it in `iex`, and then call `Sample.doIt` works fine.

```
E:\elixir>iex hello.exs
Hello World via Function
Interactive Elixir (1.0.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> require Sample
nil
iex(2)> Sample.doIt "Hello"
Hello
:ok
iex(3)>
```

If I try to `require Sample` in my file above, like below

```
defmodule Sample
  ... rest of stuff as shown above ...
end

require Sample

Sample.doFunc "Hello World via Function"
Sample.doIt "Hello World from Macro!"
```

I get error

```
** (CompileError) hello.exs:11: module Sample is not loaded but was defined. This happens because you are trying to use a module in the same context it is defined. Try defining the module outside the context that requires it.
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1352: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1353: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual you need to require a module before using its macros to signify to the compiler the order of compilation of the modules:

```
defmodule Other do
  def run do
    require Sample

    Sample.doFunc "Hello World via Function"
    Sample.doIt "Hello World from Macro!"
  end
end

Other.run # => Hello World via Function
          #    Hello World from Macro!
```

Comment: Here too, you defined a function `run` in another module in order to use the `Sample.doIt` - is this the only way to use a macro - call it via another function which is enclosed in a Module

Comment: That seems to be a limitation of the compiler. As the error says - you can't use Macros from a module in the same context where the module is defined. I'm guessing it has to do with how the compiler orders things for compilation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The macros are expanded at compile time so when we parse `defmodule Foo` followed by `Foo.some_macro`, we still haven't compiled `Foo`, so we have no idea how to expand the macro.